# how to indent continued function parameters with uncrustify?

Tags: c++, uncrustify

Consider this code:

```
some_function(1, 2
  3);
some_function(
  1, 2, 3);
```

Is there a way to make uncrustify indent the second line so that the `3` is in the column after the `(`? Preferably *without* changing the indent on the fourth line?

The doc makes it sound like `indent_func_call_param = false` should have the desired effect, but I've tried both `true` and `false` with no effect. (And yes, `use_indent_func_call_param` is `true`.)

I'm using Uncrustify-0.67-54-21651401...

Comment: Never heard of that tool. The industry-standard is *probably* clang-format. Works nicely for me so far.

Comment: I've tried both clang-format and uncrustify. Both have a *lot* of issues (see LLVM bugs 37702 - 37711, and 20449). However, I'm interested in uncrustify because it has WAY more options than clang-format. Many of the problems with clang-format is that it's like classic Ford. It will give you any code style you like, as long as what you like is LLVM style ;-).

Comment: Lol. =D I'm easy to please in this regard; my mantra is "Just pick one style and stick with it." As long as it does not get stupid of course; don't indent with 1024 tabs.  So clang-format is just fine for me.

Comment: An empty config does what you want, meaning that something that you have put into your config file is disabling that functionality. Post your config so that I can look at it. One possible option that might be causing this is: `indent_continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per CDanU's comment, the answer is: don't set `indent_continue`.